# winston 3.2.1 version is not creating log file

Tags: node.js, winston

I tried to create winston(logger file) using node js.winston 2.4.0 version its sucessfully storeing info and error in log file.but latest version its created log file but cant stored error and info messages.How to fix it

**Winston.js**

```
var winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
      //
      // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
      // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
      //
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
    ]
  });
  
  //
  // If we're not in production then log to the `console` with the format:
  // `${info.level}: ${info.message} JSON.stringify({ ...rest }) `
  // 
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.simple()
    }));
  }
```

**app.js**

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Root file of the application.
 */

// Import ExpressJS
const winston = require('winston');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// StartUp Processes
require('./startup/logging_error_startup');
require('./startup/routes_startup')(app);
require('./startup/check_security_key_startup')();
require('./startup/validation_startup')();
require('./startup/swagger_startup')(app);
require('./startup/production_startup')(app);
// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 4202;
app.listen(port, () => winston.info(`Server Started and Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**I got the output**

```
winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"message":"Server Started and Listening on port 4202","level":"info"}
```

Comment: Have you given write permission for the log directory?

Comment: how to give write permission to log directory? @narayansharma91

Comment: chmod - R 777 /your/log/directory (if you are using ubuntu)

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the logger object from `Winston.js` file into `app.js`. In your `app.js` code, the Winston import is for the npm package and not for the logger object created in `Winston.js`.

In Winston.js, export the logger object:

```
var winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
      //
      // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
      // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
      //
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
    ]
  });

  //
  // If we're not in production then log to the `console` with the format:
  // `${info.level}: ${info.message} JSON.stringify({ ...rest }) `
  // 
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.simple()
    }));
  }

module.exports = logger;
```

And in app.js, use that logger object after importing.

```
const logger = require('./Winston'); //assuming Winston.js is in the same folder level as app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// StartUp Processes
require('./startup/logging_error_startup');
require('./startup/routes_startup')(app);
require('./startup/check_security_key_startup')();
require('./startup/validation_startup')();
require('./startup/swagger_startup')(app);
require('./startup/production_startup')(app);
// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 4202;
app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`Server Started and Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can modify the default logger in your `winston.js` with

```
var winston = require('winston');

const newLogger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [.........

winston.add(newLogger);
```

instead of

```
var winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({....

module.exports = logger
```

and import the default logger in each file with

```
const logger = require('winston')

logger.info('log');
```

without dealing with relative paths each time you import the logger to different files.